# Get request in java application using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format

Tags: java, get, x-www-form-urlencoded

When I try and send a request to my server, the server only gets POST requests no matter if I set setRequestMethod("GET") . This is the function I am calling, with an url and 2 params I need to send with them:

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead,String urlParameters) {
    try {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
            conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.close();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            rd.close();
            return result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome or any other functions to be able to send a GET request to a server by sending the URL and two parameters.

Comment: Setting the content type, the content length and writing bytes to the connection output stream makes no sense for a GET request. GET requests don't have a content. request parameters of a GET request are part of the URL: ?foo=bar&baz=qux

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications but still it did not work. I have tried both with and without  the additional key values but it still did not work, it only worked for post requests. I used a post to actually get the things needed but thanks though.

Comment: *What* is still not working? I can't read code that you don't post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getHTML("http://localhost:8080/TestDynamicProject/getdata.do?t1=tp1&t2=tp2"));
    }

    public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
        try {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = conn.getInputStream();
            }

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            rd.close();
            return result.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Response from GET | Request parameters: t1=[tp1],t2=[tp2]
```

**Given below is my `Servlet`:**

```
@WebServlet("/getdata.do")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public TestServlet() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        request.getParameterMap().forEach((k, v) -> sb.append(k.toString() + "=" + Arrays.toString(v) + ","));
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        response.getWriter().append("Response from GET").append(" | Request parameters: ").append(sb);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Response from POST");
    }
}
```